# ValueError: With n_samples=0, test_size=0.3 and train_size=None, the resulting train set will be empty. Adjust any of the aforementioned parameters

Tags: python, encoding, linear-regression, valueerror

I am working with linear regression on a CSV file and I have been encoding all of the categorical values.
There are some numerical values (e.g. years) that would only be correlated to the target variables if they are changed as well.
My code runs smoothly but once I encode one of the numerical features the following way:

```
    subset_2=[1088, 1096, 1174, 1185, 1237, 1304, 1362, 1414, 1479]
    subset_1=[568, 571, 573, 574, 590 ,626 ,631, 636, 644, 651, 700, 725, 743, 762, 797, 167, 192, 332, 370, 403 ,438, 445]
    
def encode_2ndFlrSF(x):
    if x==[i for i in subset_2]:
        return 30
    elif x==[i for i in subset_1]:
        return 20
    else:
        return 10
df['2ndFlrSF'] = df['2ndFlrSF'].apply(encode_2ndFlrSF)
df['2ndFlrSF'] =df['2ndFlrSF'].apply(encode_2ndFlrSF)
```

I get the following error:

````
```

    ValueError: With n_samples=0, test_size=0.3 and train_size=None
    
    the resulting train set will be empty

. Adjust any of the aforementioned parameters.
````

I cannot understand why my encoding causes this problem and how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

scikit new version have some problems, try installing older one (version 0.19.1):

Windows:

```
pip install scikit-learn==0.19.1
```

Linux:

```
sudo python36 -m pip install scikit-learn==0.19.1
```

Comment: seems more like a comment. and I don't think it's an issue with scikit-learn